# vcr.py store call from twitter api

Tags: python, testing, vcr

I want to use https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/ and check API requests https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy or https://github.com/agriffis/vcrpy-unittest.

From lines 30:

https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter/api.py#L30

```
30: import requests
```

and later on:

```
        res = requests.post(url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',
                            data={'grant_type': 'client_credentials'},
headers=post_headers)
        # ... etc ...
```

Yet when doing something like:

```
from vcr_unittest import VCRTestCase
import vcr
import twitter
from django.conf import settings


class TwitterRetrievalAndStorageTests(VCRTestCase):
    @vcr.use_cassette()
    def test_recorded_session(self):
        api = twitter.Api(
            consumer_key=settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
            consumer_secret=settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
            access_token_key=settings.TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY,
            access_token_secret=settings.TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET)

        statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name='nntaleb')
        for s in statuses:
            print(s)
```

Not a cassette file is being created. Is there a way to do this with python-twitter?

Answer (score 1):

VCRTestCase is built on top of vcr. It doesn't make much sense to use both simultaneously. If you remove the line `@vcr.use_cassette()`, you should see a cassette named TwitterRetrievalAndStorageTests.test_recorded_session.yaml (or json) in your cwd. If instead, you don't inherit from VCRTestCase and use `@vcr.use_cassette()`, the cassette name should be `test_recorded_session.yaml` and it should be in the same folder as your class.

In general, if you use both, I have noticed that vcr takes precedence over vcrpy-unittest but that is not consistently the case.